# Selection Sort Not Working - Missing logic

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection

Using selection sort to sort an array. I think my logic is right but there's this stupid error.

```
    public static void arraySort(int[] a) {
    //for loop to go through array
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int temp = a[i]; //set a temp value for first value
        for (int x = i + 1; x < a.length; x++) {
            if (a[x] < temp) {
                a[i] = a[x];
                temp = a[x];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end it keeps printing only one group of values repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You should track the minimum index in the outer loop and swap two elements after each inner loop completion, e.g.:

```
for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
  minIndex = i;
  for (j = i; j < size; j++) {
    if (array[j] < array[minIndex]) {
      minIndex = j;
    }
  }
  swap(array, i, minIndex);
}
```

Your fixed code:

```
public static void arraySort(int[] a) {
    //for loop to go through array
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        int temp = a[i]; //set a temp value for first value
        int minIndex = i;
        for (int x = i + 1; x < a.length; x++) {
            if (a[x] < temp) {
                a[i] = a[x];
                temp = a[x];
                minIndex = x;
            }
        }
        //swap
        a[minIndex] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
    }
}
```